# Drawing on a label that's a layer behind a table

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qlabel

In my application I have a table in the foreground. It has a transparent background so I can see a label with an image through it. Both the table and the label have the exact same size.

I want to draw on the label while the table is still viewable, but not usable. Since the label is a layer behind the table, I just can't draw on it, even if I disable the table and disable the focus. It only works if the label is in the foreground which however would mean that the table is not visible anymore.

I want to draw as soon as I hit a button:

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_draw_clicked()
{
  fg_table->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
  fg_table->setEnabled(false);
  bg_label->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
  bg_label->setFocus();
}
```

Which however is not working. The table is disabled and not usable (which is correct), but drawing on `bg_label` is not possible.

In the Designer the `bg_label` is a placeholder for the class '`DrawLabel`' which inherits from QLabel. In the class drawing is made possible and I can react to various mouse events. Everything works fine and in theory I can draw, but just not if the `bg_label` is a layer behind the table.

I know that you can raise/lower the layer of a widget with

```
  bg_label->activateWindow();
  bg_label->raise();
```

but this is not what I want. The layers should not be changed and I just want to draw behind the table on `bg_label`.

Is there any way to achieve this? I haven't seen a similar problem anywhere.

Comment: I think you'll need to explain more precisely what you mean by "I just can't draw on it".  Do you mean it doesn't receive paint events or that it doesn't interact with user events?

Comment: So I can draw on my label just like in this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html
This means I also have mouse press, move and release events as well as a paint event. It all works fine when the label is the top layer, but it's behind the table, it does not work. No mouse event gets called and so nothing will be painted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `fg_table` is visually transparent is irrelevant.  The simple fact is that `fg_table` will receive all mouse events.  Those that it doesn't accept will be propogated to the parent -- not necessarily the widget that appears to be visually underneath -- i.e. `bg_label`.

Assuming the foreground table *doesn't* need to interact with mouse events you could probably use...

```
fg_table->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
```

That *should* result in all mouse events going to `bg_label`.

Comment: I added this but for some reason the table now does accept mouse events which can be seen by the dotted selection, even though I disabled the table. Before nothing happened when I clicked on the widgets, now it selects a cell as described.

Comment: If that's really the case then I'm not convinced the code you're using is as you've described.  Please edit your question to show more relevant code -- preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Actually it was a problem in my application, your solution just works fine as I tried it in a fresh program. Since it's a bit complicated to explain and nobody will share this special problem, I'll just accept your answer and I'm happy that it works now!